# How to concatenate the value of an integer variable to another variable name in python?

Tags: python, concatenation

Suppose the variable x = 1 and value_1 = 10. Is there a way for me to make the name of the second variable "value_+x" so that it gives an output 10?

Comment: Yes: Use a `dict` and have strings as keys which are the same names as the variables that you want. Then you will be able to concatenate strings together to create keys to your `dict`.